# Converting JSON to CSV in Python, handling dictionary inside exported field

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to convert queried open source data ([here, for reference](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2)) to csv. I'm able to access and query the data using the `requests` package as follows:

```
import requests
import gzip
import csv

url = "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/6zsd-86xi.json"
response = requests.get(url)
print response.status_code
if response.status_code == 200:
    print "Connection successful. Decoding JSON"
    data = response.json()
```

Each row of data has up to 22 columns that may or may not be present. If the data for a column is not present, the JSON pair will not be present, causing KeyErrors. To try and fix this, I'm using the `csv.DictWriter` class with the `field_names` and `restval=None` parameter:

```
field_names = ['id',
               'case_number',
               'date',
               'block',
               'iucr',
               'primary_type',
               'description',
               'location_description',
               'arrest',
               'domestic',
               'beat',
               'district',
               'ward',
               'community_area',
               'fbi_code',
               'x_coordinate',
               'y_coordinate',
               'year',
               'updated_on',
               'latitude',
               'longitude',
               'location'
               ]

file_name = 'open_data_test.csv.gz'
local_file = gzip.open('/tmp/' + file_name, "wb")

output = csv.DictWriter(local_file,
                    fieldnames=field_names,
                    restval=None,
                    extrasaction='ignore',
                    delimiter='|',
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                    quotechar='"',
                    doublequote=True,
                    lineterminator='\n')

for row in data:
    output.writerow(row)
```

This writes the data, however the last column 'location' is itself a dictionary containing "type" and "coordinates" (for example: `"{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-87.711766, 41.880909]}"`). I only want the 'coordinates' data, if it exists.

How can I only write the 'coordinates' section of this column to the output file, if the data is present? Editing `field_names` to include `'location'[1]` or `'location'['coordinates']` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How about looping through your `dict.keys()` and if the `key == 'coordinates'` then write only `dict['coordinates']` ?

Comment: `if 'location' in row: row['location'] = row['location']['coordinates']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your row has location data transform it to your desired format:

```
for row in data:
    if 'location' in row:
        row['location'] = row['location']['coordinates']
    output.writerow(row)
```